# How do you get calc to do the calculations in the less compiler and only render the result

Tags: less

I have the following code...

```
 top: calc(extract(@item-top, @index) / @container-height * 100%);
```

And it is compiled in the Less compiler to this...

```
top: calc(864 / 1080 * 100%);
```

But I would like it to compile to:

```
top: 80%;
```

I have tried variations of using ~ to prefix the calc and the code inside the calc but nothing seems to work. It compiles okay, it just dosn't return a value, normally its this but crossed out with a yellow exclimation in a triangle in the inspector...

```
top: calc(extract(@item-top, @index) / @container-height * 100%);
```